# Angular routing is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to do routing in angular js and Server is running fine.  But angular routing is not working properly, only main.html page is coming in ng-view, second.html is not coming.  when clicked on the first and second in html same mainController is working not the secondController.

HTML

```
<!Doctype html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<meta charset=utf-8" />
 <head>


<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-route.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="app.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
    <li><a href="#/"><i></i>first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/second"><i></i>Second</a></li>
</header>

    <div class = "container">



    <div ng-view> 

                </div>

        </body>
```

main.html

```
<h1> this is main </h1>
```

second.html

```
 <h1> this is second </h1>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

.when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
})

.when('/second',{
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController',
})

   });

     myApp.controller('mainController',
       ['$scope','$log','$location',function($scope,$log,$location){

        $log.info($location.path());
        console.log("first");

  }]);

   myApp.controller('secondController',
       ['$scope','$log','$location',function($scope,$log,$location){

        $log.info($location.path());
        console.log("second");

  }]);
```

Comment: Do you got error in your console ?

Comment: Where is the "secondController" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `scripts`, they are not working use the one from `googleapis`.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: '<h1>Main Page</h1>',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/second', {
            template: '<h1>{{ test }}</h1>',
            controller: 'secondController',
        })
});
myApp.controller('mainController',
    ['$scope', '$log', '$location', function ($scope, $log, $location) {
        $log.info($location.path());
        console.log("first");
    }])
    .controller('secondController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Testing angular routes';
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<header>
    <li><a href="#!/"><i></i>first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/second"><i></i>Second</a></li>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: why is this not running with script
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js">
     </script>

Comment: do not change it to template....not running with templateUrl
(want to include bigger html file)

Comment: change `template` to `templateUrl: 'pages/main.html'`